# ValueError: unsupported format character '}' when use % string formatting

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm trying to generate some LaTeX markup by using Python % string formatting.  I use named fields in the string and use a dictionary with matching keys for the data.  However, I get the error `ValueError: unsupported format character '}'`.  Why isn't this code working?

```
LaTeXentry = '''\\subsection{{%(title)}}
    \\begin{{itemize}}
    \\item 
    %(date)
    \\item
    %(description)
    \\item
    Source:\\cite{{%(title)}}
    \\item
    filename(s):
    %(filename)
    \\item 
    Contributed by %(name)'''

LaTeXcodeToAdd = LaTeXentry % {
    "time" : Timestamp,
    "date" : date,
    "description" : summary, 
    "filename" : filename,
    "name" : name,
    "title": title,
}
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_directory", line 115, in <module>
    "title": title,
ValueError: unsupported format character '}' (0x7d) at index 21
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `s` like in standard formating `%s` - so you need `%(title)s`, `%(date)s`, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem for whatever reason.

Comment: you have to add `s` in many places - `%(title)s`, `%(date)s`, `%(description)s`, again `%(title)s`, `%(filename)s`, `%(name)s` . Maybe you forgot one of them.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was an idiot and missed a hidden one. Luckily regex caught it for me!